# How to speed up my python progrm

Tags: python, live-streaming

```
def dehaze(img, light_intensity, windowSize, t0, w,s1,s2,siz,size1,dark_channel):        
    global outimg
    for y in range(s1,siz):
        for x in range(s2,size1):
            t = 1.0 - (w * img.item(y, x, dark_channel) / light_intensity)
            outimg.itemset((y,x,0), max(0, min(((img.item(y,x,0) - light_intensity) / max(t, t0) + light_intensity), 255)))
            outimg.itemset((y,x,1), max(0, min(((img.item(y,x,1) - light_intensity) / max(t, t0) + light_intensity), 255)))
            outimg.itemset((y,x,2), max(0, min(((img.item(y,x,2) - light_intensity) / max(t, t0) + light_intensity), 255)))
```

I implemented a program in python , i want to process live video it in a real time. But the above function is taking 1.5 sec to process one frame. Can anyone help me how can i get my desire output?
I will be thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: If you _must_ use Python, find out how to convert your code to NumPy. Otherwise, do _not_ use Python. Python is not for real-time jobs.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer would be "Don't use Python". According to the official documentation

> Compared to indexing syntax, itemset provides some speed increase for placing a scalar into a particular location in an ndarray, if you must do this. However, generally this is discouraged: among other problems, it complicates the appearance of the code. Also, when using itemset (and item) inside a loop, be sure to assign the methods to a local variable to avoid the attribute look-up at each loop iteration.

Therefore, you can at least have something like that:

```
itemset = outimg.itemset
for ...
    itemset(...)
```

At least, you will speed up the attribute look-up. The same observation holds for `img.item`. On the other hand, you don't need to compute 3 times `max(t, t0)`, so you can also store it in a variable.

One observation also: is it necessary to have a global variable ?